# How do I utilize hostnames on a local server?

Tags: dns, hostname, domain-name, dynamic-dns

I'm familiar with buying hostnames/domains and vaguely familiar with DNS servers for resolving domains to IP addresses, but, for a home solution I know absolutely nothing.

Let's say I want to host a couple of websites on my home server running Server 2012 R2. I've installed the DNS service but I don't think that's going to be the solution to this. I've looked at using DynDNS before but I'm not sure if there's a way to do what I want for cheaper or even free. I want to be able to purchase hostnames and bind them to HTTP headers on my server. My IP doesn't particularly change as far as I know so I don't believe I need dynamic DNS services, just throwing that out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your own domain, say for independence from a DynDNS solution, you can set the DNS of the domain through the person who you bought it from, to CNAME a DynDNS entry. Or, if you prefer, set the A record of the domain to your IP address. You can do this if you're happy that you have to change it when ever your ISP IP lease expires or changes.

Once you've done that, its just a matter of configuring your web server. Apache is fairly straight forward and there's a good guide here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

HTTP 1.1 requests (which nearly ALL clients make) contain a Host: header which tells the web server which virtual host the request is for, so you can host multiple domains on the same IP.

IIS has a similar concept described here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816576

Though I'd stick to Apache since it gives you platform independence too.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Apache and configuring the server, but I highly recommend not to do this, as one slip up in your local security measures, and a hacker can steal your entire domain name.

Put simply: If you need to ask this question, then you don't know enough to keep your domain secure.

Put another way: If you need to ask this question, then you should not be trying this.

Comment: Describe what you mean by a hacker stealing the entire domain name. That'd need to be done at the registry, not at the local system. Breaking the local system does not allow a domain take over. On the other hand getting write access to the local file system may allow for some alterations of the website contents, but that's a different issue.

Comment: I don't think either answers really help much. I'm trying to find out of there's a guide or solution or some steps that I can use to configure DNS or hostname resolution on Server 2012. I have the DNS Service/Role installed, so can I use that if I purchase a domain name and configure forward look up zones? I mean "you can do this using Apache and configuring it" is pretty vague...

Comment: You should use www2 for a local server. If you don't already know apache then you should not be attempting this! Unless you don't care about security. You're a hacker's playground.

Comment: I disagree. Plain Apache is fine, it will serve static content, Apache itself will not become a hackers playground. Perhaps if you put PHP on and WordPress without applying security updates. The only issue I know of which affects Apache alone was the Sloaris attack, and that was just a denial of service since it sent requests at 1character per second it would tie up the threads. Harmless from a data point of view, but harmful from a service point of view since it would tie up all threads.